# How to watch remote Akka Actor?

Tags: scala, akka, typesafe-stack, akka-remote-actor

I am learning akka-remote and one of the things I do in my `LocalActorSystem` is getting remote actor reference and send messages to him

```
class LocalActor extends Actor {
  val remote = context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:5150/user/RemoteActor")
  var counter = 0

  def receive = {
    case "START" =>
      remote ! "Hello from the LocalActor"
    case msg: String =>
      println(s"LocalActor received message: '$msg'")
      if (counter < 5) {
        sender ! "Hello back to you"
        counter += 1
      }
  }
}
```

My `Remote` looks like

```
object Remote extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("HelloRemoteSystem", ConfigFactory.load("remote"))
  val remoteActor = system.actorOf(Props[RemoteActor], name = "RemoteActor")
  remoteActor ! "The RemoteActor is alive"
}

class RemoteActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: String =>
      println(s"RemoteActor received message '$msg'")
      sender ! "Hello from the RemoteActor"
  }
}
```

I also wanted to watch `remoteActor` so that if its dead, LocalActorSystem get to know. So I did

```
  val remote = context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:5150/user/RemoteActor")
  context watch remote
```

but then compiler fails with following message

[image]

**Question**

1. How come I am able to send message to `ActorSelection` since it is not `Actor`?
2. How can I watch RemoteActor?

**Update**
However, the deprecated API does not complain

```
val remote = context.actorFor("akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:5150/user/RemoteActor")
  context watch remote
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do a lookup via `actorSelection`, that type of object you get back is an `ActorSelection` and not an `ActorRef`.  Now, an `ActorSelection` does support both `tell (!)` and `ask (?)` so you can interact with it the same way you would an `ActorRef`.  But an looking up actors via `actorSelection` supports the concept of a wild card, so the `ActorSelection` you get back potentially represents more than one actor and would allow you to send messages to more than one actor.  For instance, if you did :

`system.actorSelection("/user/foo/*")`

this would give you an `ActorSelection` for all children under the parent `ActorRef` bound to the name `foo`.  If there were two children and you send a message via that `ActorSelection`, that message would be delivered to both children.

In your case, it looks like you are looking up a single actor instance.  In that case, you can get an `ActorRef` from your `ActorSelection` by calling `resolveOne` on it.  This will return a `Future[ActorRef]` that when completed will provide you with an `ActorRef` that you can watch remotely.  You could also send the `ActorSelection` an `Identify` message and wait for the `ActorIdentity` response containing the ref to watch.

You should check out the docs [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.11/scala/actors.html), specifically the `Identifying Actors via Actor Selection` section.